# Alter script to remove class on active <ul> target

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

In my horizontal menu / submenu I'm coding I have a **class="hidden"** on the **subMenuBarWrapper ul** that I'd like to remove on the active ul on mouseenter.
Currently I have .toggle which is okay but I'd prefer the "class" way instead. Could someone help me with a possible solution? Thanks.

HTML

```
   <div class="subMenuBarWrapper">
     <ul data-parentid="1" class="hidden">
            <li class="">
                   <a href="etc....</a>
                       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

JS

```
 $('.nav_options li a').on('mouseenter', function () {
        var targetmatch = $(this).attr('data-submenunum');
        $('.subMenuBarWrapper ul').each(function () {
        $(this).toggle(targetmatch.length < 1 || $(this).attr('data-parentid').indexOf(targetmatch) > -1);
     });
});
```

Comment: $(this).removeClass('hidden') ?

Comment: Add your full menu html please, or at least the part containing the `subMenuBarWrapper` class

Answer (score 0):

You can use your exact same logic and use `toggleClass()`:

```
$(this).toggleClass('hidden', targetmatch.length < 1 || $(this).data('parentid').indexOf(targetmatch) > -1);
```

The first argument is the class name to use, and the second is a boolean to determine whether this should be added to or removed from the element in question. Also, note the use of `.data()` over `.attr('data-...')`

Comment: Rory, that's doing to opposite of what's needed ;) the one selected <ul> out of the three that I have  n my submenu has the class:hidden and all the others have been removed.

Comment: I'm confused, as the logic here is equivalent to the code in your question. Can you add a working example in a http://jsfiddle.net to show exactly what you want.

Comment: Your not as confused as I am, I can assure you. Do you think I should add a mouseleave function too or not, would it make it easier?